# Proof of definite integral is finite

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

it is given that, $0 < g(x) < 1$ and
\begin{eqnarray}
I_1 = \int^{+\infty}_{-\infty} g(x) dx \\
I_2 = \int^{+\infty}_{-\infty} g(x) x^2 dx \\
\end{eqnarray}
exists and are finite. I need to prove that

\begin{equation}
I_3 = \int^{+\infty}_{-\infty} g(x) \ln [g(x)] dx
\end{equation}

aslo exists and is finite.

It is clear that, $\lim_{x \to \infty} g(x) = 0$ but in this case $\lim_{x \to \infty}\ln[g(x)] = - \infty $. I tried to generate inequality for $\ln [g(x)]$ and writing 
$$g(x) = \frac{1}{(x^2+a^2)^{1+\delta}} \hspace{1cm} for \hspace{.2cm} x>M$$ but not able to go anywhere after that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $$A = \{x: |x|>1, g(x) < e^{-x^2}\}$$ $$B = \{x: g(x) \ge e^{-x^2}\}$$ $$ C = \{x: |x|<1, g(x) < e^{-x^2}\}$$
Clearly
$$ \int_B g(x) |\ln(g(x))| \, dx \le \int_B g(x) x^2 \, dx < \infty .$$
On $A$, we have $g(x) |\ln(g(x)| \le x^2 e^{-x^2}$ because $- y \ln y$ is a decreasing function on $[0,e^{-1}]$.  So
$$ \int_A g(x) |\ln(g(x))| \, dx \le \int_A x^2 e^{-x^2} \, dx < \infty .$$
On $C$ we have $g(x) |\ln(g(x)| \le e^{-1}$ because $-y \ln y$ attains its maximum at $y = e^{-1}$.
$$ \int_C g(x) |\ln(g(x))| \, dx \le \int_{[-1,1]} e^{-1} \, dx < \infty .$$